# angular material mat-table: how to multiply two column values in a 3rd column

Tags: angular, angular-material, calculated-columns, calculation, mat-table

I have an angular material table with a dropdown column by which users can select the time length. After users provide the number of time, I wanted to calculate the service fee for each service type and then do a total to sum a total for all selected services.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ukB.jpg

The issue is the sub total (price * months) for all rows dynamically changes based on the last selected  number of month although the previously selected months remain no change.
This is my template

```html
......
<ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Price (USD/m) </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price | currency}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>                                        
<ng-container matColumnDef="month">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Months </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-select placeholder="0" (selectionChange)="onChangeMonth($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month.value">
                {{ month.viewValue }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select> 
    </mat-cell>                     
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="subtotal">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SubTotal </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.price * serviceLength}}
    </mat-cell>                               
</ng-container> 

......
```

And this is my ts:

```js
export class StockAddsubsComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['id','name','price','month','subtotal'];
  listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;  
  months: any [] = [{value: 1, viewValue: 1}, {value: 3, viewValue: 3}, {value: 6, viewValue: 6}, {value: 12, viewValue: 12}
  ]; 
  serviceLength: number;
  
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  
  constructor(private feesService: FeesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFeeList();
  }

  createFeeList() {                
    this.feesService.getFeeList().subscribe((data: []) => {
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  } 

  onChangeMonth(event) {
    this.serviceLength = event.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change `event.value` to `event.target.value`

Comment: Do you want to calculate subtotal for individual rows ?

Comment: Yes, I took Eliseo's solution. that works as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `[(ngModel)]="element.month"` in your `mat-select`

```
<mat-select placeholder="0" [(ngModel)]="element.month">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month.value">
    {{ month.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And use `{{element.price*element.month}}`

NOTE: You can also use a getter to get the total and put in the footer of the table

```
get total()
{
    return this.listData.data.map(x=>x.month*x.price).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntdkhl?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Hi Eliseo, thank you so much. your solution works as I expected. You did save me. For my case, how I can set the default value to "0", so that I won't get "NaN" for Subtotal and Total when any row is not set a value? Early, I set placeholder="0" , which just looks like default value.

Comment: try `{{+element.price*(+element.month)}}` (the plus sign convert the string to number)

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. the issue remains. Could you please provide any other possible solution?

Comment: take a look to the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntdkhl?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: it's possible you has a typo error (check the name of your variables). Also you can try `{{element.month?+element.month*(+element.price):0}}` (if element.month element.month*element.price else zero)

Comment: Wow! greatly appreciated! Now every row does display "0". The only thing is "get total()" gets NaN although all rows have "0" value. The total won't change unless every row get an actual value by selecting a number of month. How the total() method can  be correspondingly modified please? Thanks!

Comment: the total() method emits an error: " Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

Comment: true, at first `listData`is "indefined", Typical we check if listData has value using ternary operator: `return this.listData?this.listData.data.map(x=>x.month*x.price).reduce((a,b)=>a+b):0`

Comment: Thanks! This is good. The only thing remains that the get total() returns "NaN" . This won't change until selection is made to each row for month with any value. That means that those "0" seem string value and thus the total() function failed to sum all the row's subtotal (including "0" like values) unless the total() can exclude any string value in any rows.

Comment: `this.listData.data.map(x=>+x.month*(+x.price)).reduce((a,b)=>a+b):0 ` the "plus" sign try to convert the string to number

Comment: I do have question in regards to mat table and it seems you have expertise here  can you please help me to resolve this mat table issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an