# How to show split header in the material table having nested group of data in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-ui

I am having trouble displaying data in the material table when the data is coming as a nested array of objects.

I would like to display the table which is currently displayed in the stackblitz.

If I changed the existing data with my **newData** variable it will start breaking whole table.

Can anybody guide me How I can achieve split header function with group of nested data in the material table?

I would like to achieve something like this.

Here is my stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-5foa62

[image]

Comment: Are you using "code" field inside "summary" obect?

Comment: yes first column "No" is coming from the code field

Comment: As you have grouping data means nested array also. The best way to handling it using a nested table inside a parent table.

Comment: Thanks vimal.. How I can make sticky header to this table ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430713/angular-material-table-spitted-headers-add-the-sticky-header-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data source need to be an array of data you want to display. So you have to change

```
dataSource1 = newData;
```

to

```
dataSource1 = newData.data.summary;
```

You will also need to change the columns in the template since the objects are different, for example:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="similar-cell-width">{{ element.data[0].amount }}</td>
```

Comment: thanks for answer Chris..what if the positions will change in the array? Is there anyway to check the condition before using element.data[0].amount?

Comment: you can use regular typescript code between the `{{ }}`, even call a method (like `{{ processData(element) }}`). So you can do whatever array manipulation you want here.

Comment: Sorry, if I am asking much. Is it possible for you to provide an example in the stackblitz?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-5foa62

Comment: Thanks Chris.. it worked, I just have one question that how I can apply style to header now? I am not able to add sticky header here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430713/angular-material-table-spitted-headers-add-the-sticky-header-functions