# Angular Material Table spitted headers add the sticky header functions

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, mat-table

I am having the spitted header angular material table and I was looking for help to add the sticky header.

I have tried to using sticky: true but somehow it is not working for my first column (as I am hiding the column.) And for the first rows. It is showing the second row.

Below is my table

[image]

When I go with the dropdown only these headers get sticky behavior than others.
[image]

Below is my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-5foa62

Answer (score 1):

To make the top header sticky add sticky tag in that as well. It will also fixed first column sticky issue.

```
 <tr mat-header-row
     *matHeaderRowDef="['header-row-first-group','header-row-sec-group','header-row-third-group','header-row-forth-group','header-row-fifth-group'];sticky:true">
</tr>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-aaewxs?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it working in internet explorer and edge?

Comment: Working i chrome and edge have not tested in other browser, requesting you to please test yourself for all edge cases.

Comment: Sure. Will check and update you. Thanks a lot